# Java error: The constructor Item.ItemM() is undefined

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am having trouble running my java class with constructor. Looks like something is wrong with my constructor, but I cannot really find the error.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Item
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ItemM myItem = new ItemM();

        System.out.println("Enter item ID");
        String itemID = input.nextLine();

        myItem.setItemID(itemID);
        System.out.printf("The Item ID is %s%n", myItem.getItemID());
    }
    public class ItemM
    {
        private String itemID;

        public ItemM(String itemID)
        {
            this.itemID = itemID;
        }

        public void setItemID(String itemID)
        {
        this.itemID = itemID;
        }

        public String getItemID()
        {
            return itemID;
        }
    }

}
```

The error is:

```
ItemM myItem = new ItemM();
```

I also tried to use:

```
ItemM myItem = new ItemM(itemID);
```

I need it to be in one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Make it `static`

First your `ItemM` needs a `String` argument. And you could make your inner `class` static to allow your `static main` method to use it without an `Item` instance.

```
public static class ItemM
```

**and** then you could use

```
ItemM myItem = new ItemM("a");
```

#### Alternatively,

```
ItemM myItem = new Item().new ItemM("a");
```

#### Explanation

[JLS-8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) says (in part)

> An *inner class* is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared `static`.
>
> Inner classes include local ([§14.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)), anonymous ([§15.9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)) and non-static member classes ([§8.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5)).

Comment: @Ben Added JLS reference.